# SQL DISTINCT, GROUP BY OR....?

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008, greatest-n-per-group

I have a database with the following columns

```
SKU | designID | designColor | width | height | price | etc.
```

`SKU` number is unique and `designID` is repeated.

Basically, I want to `DISTINCT` or `GROUP BY` designID and get the value of the rest of row even though they are not repeated.

Example:

```
123 | A-1 | RED | 2 | 3 | $200 | etc.
135 | A-2 | BLU | 8 | 4 | $150 | etc.
```

After all, I should be able to sort them by either column. I already tried `GROUP BY` and `DISTINCT` but non of them return the rest of the row's value.

Example:

```
SELECT DISTINCT designID
FROM tbl_name
```

Which will return

```
A-1  
A-2
```

and no other data.

`GROUP BY` example:

```
SELECT designID, designColor
FROM tbl_name
GROUP BY designID, designColor
```

Which will return

```
A-01 | RED
A-02 | BLU
```

Any idea so I can have DISTINCT result with all the row values?

Thanks in advance.

====================================

Thanks everybody for all your time and tips, Please let me describe more;

basically I need to eliminate the repeated designID and show just one of them and it doen't matter which one of them, first, middle or last one. Important is the one I show has to have all the row information, like SKU, Price, Size, etc. I dont't know, maybe I should use a different code rather than DISTINCT or GROUP BY.

Here is what I want from database.

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. If one duplicate has a price of $150 and the other has a price of $175, which value do you want to show? Can you show real data, real duplicates, and which values you want from each column?

Comment: But if you have 2 rows with same `DesignID` and different data in the rest of the columns, what should be returned in those columns?

Comment: It is not clear to me what you want. Describe what you want but don't use SQL functions like DISTINCT to describe what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't care which row will be returned, you could use `MAX` and a [subquery-group by](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/jeffs/archive/2005/12/14/8546.aspx):

```
create table #test(
    SKU int,
    designID varchar(10),
    designColor varchar(10),
    width int,
    height int,
    price real,
    etc varchar(50)
)

insert into #test values(123, 'A-1' ,'RED', 2, 3, '200', 'etc')
insert into #test values(135, 'A-2' ,'BLUE', 8, 4, '150', 'etc')
insert into #test values(128, 'A-2' ,'YELLOW', 6, 9, '300', 'etc')

select t.*  FROM    #test t INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT    MAX(SKU) as MaxSKU,designID
    FROM      #test
    GROUP BY  designID
) tt 
ON t.SKU = tt.MaxSKU;

drop table #test;
```

Result:

```
SKU    designID designColor    width    height  price   etc
123      A-1       RED            2      3       200    etc
135      A-2       BLUE           8      4       150    etc
```

Comment: Tim, Your are a life saver. It works perfectly. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 5):

Unless I misunderstand, you can `SELECT DISTINCT` on multiple columns:

```
SELECT 
  DISTINCT designID,
  designColor,
  width,
  height,
  price
FROM tbl_name
ORDER BY designColor
```

This will give you all the unique rows. If you have, for example, two `designID` values across 15 total rows with 2 and 3 different `designColor` values respectively, this will give you 5 rows.

Comment: I thought the OP only wants to group by `designID`. "Basically, I want to DISTINCT or GROUP BY designID and get the value of the rest of row even though they are not repeated"

Answer (score 2):

If they are all guaranteed to be duplicate (100% i.e. all columns) then a distinct would be your friend. i.e.

`SELECT DISTINCT design_id, designColor, width, height, price FROM tbl_name`

This will give distinct values on everything except SKU (which will always be unique and foil your distinct.

If you want unique designId values and the other results are different, then you need to figure out which of the values you want. If you really don't care, you can just arbitarily pick and aggregate function (say, MIN) and use GROUP BY

i.e.

`SELECT designID, MIN(designColor) FROM tbl_name GROUP BY designID`

This will give you a unique design id and *a* value for the other columns.

If you want the designID for the biggest skew, you could use a ranking function i.e.

```
;WITH rankedSKUs 
AS
( 
    SELECT SKU, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY SKU DESC) as id 
    FROM tbl_name
)
SELECT * 
FROM tbl_name T
WHERE EXISTS(SELECT * FROM rankedSKUs where id = 1 and SKU = T.sku)
```

This will return all columns for each distinct designID taking the largest value for SKU as authoritative for each designed.

Answer (score 0):

If you want return every field, you might as well remove the `distinct` (assuming you have an `id` like you seem to).

Your request is really weird because if you take say,

```
SELECT DISTINCT designID
FROM tbl_name
```

you get a list of unique design id's, and if you then look up in the table for all rows with those id's, *you'll get every single row in the table*.

As a side note, the use of `distinct` usually means you designed your database badly (ie, not normalized) or that you designed your query badly (ie, you know, *really* badly). My money is on the former.

Comment: I see nothing bad in a `SELECT DISTINCT designID FROM tbl_name` query.

Comment: I agree with @ypercube, while `DISTINCT` can be a sign of poor design, I don't think that's "usually" the case. I've used it in several occasions where a complex query performed better by filtering out duplicates at the outer level instead of trying to do so with all kinds of logic in the inner queries. And for a report with 40 output columns, it beats the heck out of `GROUP BY a,b,c,d,e,f,g,...`

Comment: And it's very common to use it when dealing with cleansing of external data before putting them into the db.

Comment: @ypercube, @Aaron, @Jay, look at his update, it's exactly what I meant. Instead of using a normalized design table, he's extracting it with `distinct` from the main table. What happens when a design isn't in use by any product anymore? It dissapears. But what if you want to use it again? Again, bad database design.

Answer (score 0):

If you use LINQ you can use something like this:

```
get_data_context().my_table.GroupBy( t => t.designID ).Select( t => new { t.Key, 
    REST = t.Select( u => new { u.SKU , u.designID , u.designColor , u.width , 
    u.height , u.price } ) } );
```